# In R and knitr, how do I plot INLA results?

Tags: r, graphics, latex, knitr

I'm trying to inlude some [INLA](http://www.r-inla.org/) code in my knitr document and print plots:

Using a trivial example

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<<c1>>=
library("INLA")

n = 100
z = runif(n)
eta = 1 + 0.1*z
N = 20

p = exp(eta)/(1+exp(eta))
y = rbinom(n,  size = N, prob = p)
r = inla(y ~ 1 + z,  
         data = data.frame(y, z), 
         family = "binomial", 
         Ntrials = rep(N, n),
        control.family = list(link = "logit"), 
        control.predictor = list(compute=TRUE)
        )
@

<<c2>>=
plot(r, single=TRUE)
@

\end{document}
```

When I run this code interactively inside RStudio all works fine and I get a series of plots. However after kniting document - none of them gets included.

How can I fix that?

UPDATE 1 I posted the question asking for clarification from the package package developer on [Google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/r-inla-discussion-group/ixarmZMlTL4).

UPDATE 2 Havard Rue from INLA developers group posted a Sweave solution on Google Groups. The trick is:

```
<<results=tex, echo=FALSE>>=
figs = plot(r, single=TRUE, postscript=TRUE, prefix="Sweave/ex1/figure-")

cat("\\begin{figure}[tbp]\n")
cat("\n")
cat("\\centering\n")

for(i in 1:length(figs)) {
    cat("\\includegraphics[width=7cm,height=7cm,angle=-90]{",
    gsub("[.]eps$","",figs[i]), "}\n", sep="")
}

cat("\\caption{XXX}\n")
cat("\\label{fig:11}\n")
cat("\\end{figure}\n")
@
```

That does seem to do the job. Graphs are created in specified directory and then placed inside the pdf output. Some tinkering is necessary however for placing and sizing since the `knitr` controls doesn't seem to work any longer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I stumbled upon `INLAutils` [package](https://github.com/timcdlucas/INLAutils) that promises to solve the problem with `ggplot2`. Sample code:

```
  data(Epil)
  ##Define the model
  formula = y ~ Trt + Age + V4 +
           f(Ind, model="iid") + f(rand,model="iid")
  result = inla(formula, family="poisson", data = Epil, control.predictor = list(compute = TRUE))

  p <- autoplot(result)
```

And resulting plot:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

`INLA` seems to be doing some non-standard things when plotting. If not running in RStudio, it opens up a new plotting window (device) when it plots. I think that means that `knitr` is not seeing the plots because they are not on the device that `knitr` is using/monitoring.

Perhaps you can trick INLA by adding a chunk

```
<<>>=
op <- options(device="RStudioGD")
@
```

at the start of your knitr file and

```
<<>>=
options(op)
@
```

at the end of the file (to reset the default device to something appropriate).

This is untested because I don't have `INLA` installed.

It may require modifying `INLA` (specifically `inla.dev.new`) to not open a new device. One approach that might work is

```
noop <- function(...) NULL
assignInNamespace("inla.dev.new", noop, ns="INLA")
```

This, also, is untested and could potentially break other parts of `INLA`.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. Unfortunately didn't work - compilation stops with an error: `Error in dev.new(width = width, height = height) : 
  device 'RStudioGD' not found
Calls: knit ... call_block -> block_exec -> chunk_device -> dev.new`

Comment: @radek Agrrr... this is so ugly. I really cannot stand it after I read the source code of `INLA:::plot.inla` and `INLA:::inla.dev.new`. Why should a plotting function have the side effect of manipulating the graphics device? I recommend you to contact the package author to remove the function `inla.dev.new`. I do not think it makes sense: when in or not in RStudio, R will always automatically open a new device if a new plot comes -- there is no need to call `dev.new()` manually as the author did.

Comment: @Yihui I'm glad I'm not the only one to have that reaction on reading the source. I, too, think the authors of the package should be contacted to fix their package because I would consider that behavior a bug (although it is obviously intentional behavior).

Comment: Ben, Yihui & Brian: Thanks a lot for your input. I'll post the issue on the (active) INLA discussion group and report back on what I have learned.

Comment: @Brian Just tested your new suggestion. Pdf is now built including graphs. However all of them start on new page and do not respect `fig.width` setting.

Answer (score 3):

A response to the discussion from one of the INLA devellopers

The intended use of plot() is to generate plots (yes, many) with plots of the results. They are intended for interactive use with using a standarnd GUI/Terminal or RStudio.

When used within a knitr environment, or Sweave, then this way of generating the plots may no longer be appropriate. Issues in our package are fixed when someone make us aware of them. The fix refered to above was due to my own limited experience with Sweave, and it is known not to be the best one around.  We're happy to add any good solution for the knitr/Sweave environment, if someone just tell us what they want/need.

Best,
Håvard Rue

www.r-inla.org